# Tensorflow Feature Column for 0 and 1

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

For Tensorflow feature columns contain boolean value 0 and 1.

Should I be using `tf.feature_column.numeric_column`

or `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list`?

Comment: can you explain a bit what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sequence_categorical_column_with_identity :

```
tf.feature_column.sequence_categorical_column_with_identity('YOUR_FEATURE',2)
```

the second parameter is the number of buckets. If you have n consecutive integers [0,1,2 .. ,n-1] in your feature, you then write :

```
tf.feature_column.sequence_categorical_column_with_identity('YOUR_FEATURE',n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list.

I would think you would want to treat the data as categories, rather than as scalars.